# how can an .ASPX page get its file system path?

Tags: asp.net

I have a page something.aspx, with associated codebehind something.aspx.cs.  In that codebehind, I want to know the filesystem location of something.aspx.  Is there any convenient way to get it?

Update: I got several excellent answers, which unfortunately didn't work because of something else crazy I'm doing.  I'm encoding some additional information on the URL I pass in, so it looks like this:

http://server/path/something.aspx/info1/info2/info3.xml

The server deals with this OK (and I'm not using querystring parameters to work around some other code that I didn't write).  But when I call Server.MapPath(Request.Url.ToString()) I get an error that the full URL with the 'info' segments isn't a valid virtual path.

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the MapPath line and then inspect the properties of Request.Url. You'll find a lot of useful stuff in there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Request.PhysicalPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.physicalpath.aspx)

Comment: Winner! The Request object is so poorly organized it's hard to remember all the different places for stuff.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks!  The actual line I ended up with is:

string servicesPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Request.PhysicalPath) + @"\services\";

Answer (score 10):

```
// File path
string absoluteSystemPath = Server.MapPath("~/relative/path.aspx");
// Directory path
string dir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(absoluteSystemPath);
// Or simply
string dir2 = Server.MapPath("~/relative");
```

Comment: this implies I know what the 'relative' part is, but that's what I'm trying to calculate.

Answer (score 5):

[Server.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632.aspx) is among the most used way to do it.

```
string physicalPath = Server.MapPath(Request.Url);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Server.MapPath( Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath )`